# Python, typeerror about string and bytes

Tags: python, encoding

I used Youtube API and got list of comments.
And trying to change it into single string so I can use konlpy.

```
    a = str(' '.join(c)).encode("UTF-8")
```

But I got

"TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found"

So I tried

```
    a = str(b' '.join(c)).encode("UTF-8")
```

It pops

"TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found"

What is the problem?

+) Input c is...

```
 response = api_obj.commentThreads().list(part='snippet,replies', videoId=viedoIdd, maxResults=100).execute()

while response:
    for item in response['items']:
        comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']
        comments.append([comment['textDisplay']])

for c in comments:
    a = str(' '.join(c)).encode("UTF-8")
    words.append(a)
```

Comment: please share input c ...

Comment: Can you decompose the problem? Does it happen with `' '.join(c)`? And of course, what is `c`?

Comment: @qaiser  I added:)

Comment: @tdelaney I added:)

Comment: It might help to do `print(repr(c))` just before the join. Then you'll have the one that causes the problem.

Comment: @tdelaney There are some emojis. Is it the problem? I'm just a beginner so slow to understand...sorry

Comment: Not a problem. It seems like some comments are strings, others are bytes. Confusing! Emojis are frequently text characters but other interactions may be something like a png. If so, you'd want to check the type before the join. `' '.join(c for c in comments if isinstance(c, str))`. Something like that.

Comment: @tdelaney It doesn't work...But thank you very much!